# Is it a good practices to separate JS file based on pages?

Tags: javascript, html, http, web

For example, there are three different pages in my website which will use different js code and some common js code.

Is it a good practices to separate these js code into different files?

For example, in A.html:

```
<script src="/js/common.js"></script>
<script src="/js/pageA.js"></script>
```

in B.html:

```
<script src="/js/common.js"></script>
<script src="/js/pageB.js"></script>
```

So, when I access page A, page B related js will not be loaded, so it will be more quick I think? Am I thinking too much? its not necessary?

Or should I just put all js in one js file?

For example, in every html file:

```
<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
```

Normally which way do people do ?

Comment: its usually quicker to load two 50kb JS files than one 100kb JS file because of pipelining. for sites, i like a sitewide.js (usually a bundle), a sectionwide.js and a pagespecific.js (if needed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on your application, its size, and its purpose.

On large scale applications or single page applications (SPAs) it's common practice to separate JS files. For example, the popular HTML5 framework [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) separates it's files in this order:

```
app
-- pages
    -- pageA
        -- pageA.js
        -- pageA.html
    -- pageB
        -- pageB.js
        -- pageB.html
-- etc
```

This makes your set up much more *modular* and is used in order to make your application's code easier to debug and/or share/replicate. It is also useful if you're developing Web Components or if you're using things like TypeScript or ES6 since they have the option for exporting and importing classes.

It would make pageA load faster yes (depending on the size of your code) since it wouldn't have to load pageB's JS. This also keeps the environment cleaner since it's more of a lazy loading setup (loading files when they are required rather than loading everything at start up).

You may want to keep it all in one file if your project is small, or if there are many common functions and operations between pages. However, since you've included a common.js in your question I assume this is where you would keep all of it.

In the end, you're the developer! Code it however you like! 
I personally keep things modular and in separate files since I find myself reusing old code and it's much simpler to get it from a specific folder rather than searching through one large JS file.

Answer (score 1):

That's smart actually to separate JS for each page, but remember not to import too much JS files, because it'll increase the number of calls to the server and hence the network traffic. But in your case, a couple of files like

```
<script src="/js/common.js"></script>
<script src="/js/pageB.js"></script>
```

is really nice.

In future you may use a module bundler like [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) to bundle `common.js` and `pageB.js` in a single `mainB.js`, same will go for `mainA.js`. But you have to decide if you have that many files to use a module bundler.

Comment: webpack is the happy medium

Answer (score 1):

External scripts will be cached by the browser, so initially, loading one larger file when a user first accesses your page will cause the rest of the users visit to be seamless, which is great.

Having several .js files load *on the same page* is creating unnecessary requests and should be avoided.

If you have a chunk of code that is only required on a certain page (or pages), it really comes down to how large that chunk is; if it's huge, sure, split it up and add it on that pages that require it; however, if it's small, i'd keep everything in one .js file.

If you worry about speed, you can minimize your .js, and enable GZip compression on your server.

-

Most websites source code will show multiple scripts; this is often because they are either using a CMS (which hardly cares about your SEO needs), or using PHP "includes" which embed modules that require their own scripts to run.

I would avoid using multiple scripts if it can be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to the front-end development, I suggest you divided your js codes into these types:

1. common utils(com_utils.js)

   small code blocks which is useful in global such as login/logout operation, error handler, notifications. you should load this js file in almost every document.
2. large component modual(modulename.js)

   some codes are useful in several webpages(not all pages) and it is complicated, which means it should be re-useable, then you need design it as a seperate component, such as an editor component, image upload component.
3. un-reuseable codes(pagename.js)

   the rest codes are un-reuseable or customized for specific page. then you can name the js file pagename.js and load it in specific page.

It is important to note that this is just a beginner's guide if you want a quick start, when you have more experience in front-end development you better learn how to modular your code. It is also good for dealing different dependency relations between codes. Or, you can check third-party tools such as require.js.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in general you should separate your code for readability, maintainability, avoiding mistakes and reducing the Javascript load.

Furthermore, if your 'common.js' is large, or is object oriented, you may wish to further separate that into several files or directories. See this example of a complex app: https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/tree/master/Source

If you need to, later on, pack and/or minify your Javascript code (to make it smaller), there are build tools for Javascript like [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) or [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/).